# Regex capture last 4 same number

Tags: regex, match, phone-number

I have the phone number like this: 0988523333

This regex matched:

```
/(\d)\1{3}$/
```

But it also match these numbers like: 2961533333 or 1872333333

How can I write the pattern match the 1st number only (0988523333) ?

Comment: I mean the first phone number only (0988523333), not digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 back-references:

```
(^|\d)((?!\1)\d)\2{3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV1qY9/2)

This will make sure we match **exact 4 repeated instance of a digit** at the end.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(^|\d)     # matches a digit or line start and captures it as group #1
((?!\1)\d) # matches next digit if it is not same as group #1 and captures it as group #2
\2{3}      # matches 3 instances of group #2
```